# Form not getting submitted - Bootstrap framework

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on this project which is going fine so far, however I have this one problem which I simply can't see how to solve.

I am having a section on a page where you can edit your information.

II am checking for $_POST on the same page to avoid redirecting the site, however it seems like the submit button aren't submitting anything.

EDIT: 
I **DON'T** get any PHP error, nothin simply happens when I press the submit button.

My PHP on the same page as the form:

```
require_once("inc/functions.php");

if(isset($_POST['saveButton'])){
    $emailValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $bukserValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bukser']);
    $jakkeValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jakke-str']);
    $skoValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shoes']);
    setUserSetting($emailValue, $bukserValue, $jakkeValue, $skoValue);
};
```

My PHP function:

```
function setUserSetting($emailValue, $bukserValue, $jakkeValue, $skoValue) {
    $emailValue = strip_tags($emailValue);
    $uid = $_SESSION['usrId'];
    $sql = "UPDATE usr SET email='$emailValue', sko='$skoValue', jakke='$jakkeValue', bukser='$bukserValue' WHERE id='$uid'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if($result === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        $_SESSION['usrEmail'] = $emailValue;
        return "gemt";  
    };
};
```

And finally my html form:

```
                       <section id="settings" class="bg-light-gray">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Indstillinger</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post" role="form" name="settForm">
                    <fieldset>

                <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">E-mail</label>  
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control input-md" value="<? echo getUserSetting($usrEmail, 'mail'); ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bukser">Bukser størrelse</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select id="bukser" name="bukser" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="C44">C44</option>
                                    <option value="C46">C46</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="jakke-str">Jakke størrelse</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select id="jakke-str" name="jakke-str" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="XS">XS</option>
                                    <option value="S">S</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="shoes">Sko størrelse</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select id="shoes" name="shoes" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="36">36</option>
                                    <option value="37">37</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl text-center center-block" id="saveButton" name="saveButton">Gem ændringer</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the `action` totally,it'd redirect to the same page anyways..i think it's because you did `action=""` , therefore making your form look like `<form class="form-horizontal" action method="post" role="form" name="settForm">`

Comment: The thing is that it works on my login page: <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="login-form">.

Removing it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

*ADD value to your button! Testing it in local i saw that the button parameter is empty so isset() evalutate to false.*

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl text-center center-block" id="saveButton" name="saveButton" value="saveButton" >Gem ændringer</button>
```

As for `<input type="button">` is the value attribute that carry the button value.

*Additional details:*

First for a better practice i will separate your form with the businnes script.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" role="form" name="settForm">
```

to

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="**YOURSCRIPT.PHP**" method="post" role="form" name="settForm">
```

Your select is missing `</select>` tag

You can always clean your data from within your "controller" script, it will be a lot more maintainable.
For making a good  UX, you can add client side validation using javascript.

Additionally, mysql extension is deprecated. Go for mysqli or even better PDO.

Comment: There's no need for that, without action set it will simply submit to the current page.

Comment: He is using the same file for both presentation layer and businnes??

Comment: _"My PHP on the same page as the form:"_ <- in his question.

Comment: Yup using isset($_POST) to check on the same page, if set then collects the values and sends to a function in my "business" script :-)

Comment: This is not anyway better because leads to code bad code maintainability.

Comment: i do not see any issue in the HTML form preventing the submit of data apart the action="" attribute. Will be better if he looks what happening at the submit button in terms of http request

Comment: Edit. Found the solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the missing closing `</select>` tags in your code. And because of that php will give `Undefined index: Sko` error. So include missing tags first.

```
// your code

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="jakke-str">Jakke størrelse</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="jakke-str" name="jakke-str" class="form-control">
            <option value="XS">XS</option>
            <option value="S">S</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Sko">Sko størrelse</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="Sko" name="Sko" class="form-control">
            <option value="36">36</option>
            <option value="37">37</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

// your code
```

**Sidenote:** Please don't use the `mysql_` database extensions, they were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and were removed in PHP 7.0.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use mysql_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Hi, I updated the source code in my questions. It still does not submit at all. Thats whats wonders me.

Comment: @EmilElkjærNielsen Change your submit button may be, like this, `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-xl text-center center-block" id="saveButton" name="saveButton" value="Gem ændringer" />`

Answer (score 0):

remove 
mysql_real_escape_string() function from the code where you are fetching posted values

Comment: Never had a problem using mysql_real_escape_string() before, works in my login form as well.
See updated question - I don't get any PHP errors, it's more or less HTML based

Comment: Try once. I tried your code and the form submitted.

Comment: Makes no difference for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved.

Me who oversaw a javascript error.

Note to self: Don't code while tired :D

Thanks for your suggestions though!

Comment: Can you post your solution? since i found your button parameter empty in the request. Im courios about what javascript function can create this issue.

Comment: @YuriBlanc - Nothing changed in the posted code. I just had a .js in my project interferring with the solution, therefore it didn't work :-)